# Copy raw video frame buffer to IDirect3DSurface

Tags: directx, video-processing, video-capture, .net-6.0, winui-3

Normally, MediaPlayer has supported function `CopyFrameToVideoSurface(IDirect3DSurface destination)` to copy video frame to Direct3DSurface.

But now I receive a video frame as `byte[] pbuffer` with `width` and `Height`, how do I transfer it to IDirect3DSurface like MediaPlayer did?

Thanks

Edit:
To render video frame of MediaPlayer, I use:

```
    public void VideoFrameAvailable(Windows.Media.Playback.MediaPlayer sender, object args)
    {
                var swapChain = _swapChain.Object;
                using var dxgiSurface = swapChain.GetBuffer<IDXGISurface>(0);
                var dxgiSurfacePtr = Marshal.GetComInterfaceForObject<IDXGISurface, IDXGISurface>(dxgiSurface.Object);
                CreateDirect3D11SurfaceFromDXGISurface(dxgiSurfacePtr, out var graphicsSurface).ThrowOnError();
                Marshal.Release(dxgiSurfacePtr);
                using var d3DSurface = MarshalInterface<IDirect3DSurface>.FromAbi(graphicsSurface)!;
                Marshal.Release(graphicsSurface);

                sender.CopyFrameToVideoSurface(d3DSurface);
                swapChain.Present(1, 0).ThrowOnError(); 
    }
```

Comment: CopyFrameToVideoSurface copies the current Media Player video frame to the provided IDirect3DSurface. You don't get to choose which frame. Where do you get those bytes from? Do you have a reference to an IDirect3DSurface  object? Or what are you trying to do?

Comment: I receive video frame buffer(byte[]) returned by event from other library (video frame will be sent continuously), now I want to use directX to render those frame as a video. So, I think I need to copy the frame to IDirect3DSurface is a first step.

Comment: To use winrt's MediaPlayer you must provide a MediaSource (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/play-audio-and-video-with-mediaplayer). There are multiple type of supported input MediaSource (file, steam, etc.) but what seems the most appropriate in your case is from a MediaFrameSource see this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/process-media-frames-with-mediaframereader